# Java Hibernate - How to write this in Java

Tags: java, c#, hibernate

I need to rewrite some of our Web services in Java (originally in C#)
How do I write this simple C# code in Java?

```
var vdoList = db.tbl_videos.GroupBy(s => s.VideoUploadedDate.Value.Year);
List<dynamic> groups = new List<dynamic>();
foreach (var item in vdoList)
{
    groups.Add(new { Year = item.Key, Count = item.Count() });
}
```

As a start I tried to use

```
List gg = session.createCriteria(TblVideos.class).setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("videoCategory"))
                        .list();
```

but I just get a list of **VideoCategory** strings

Thanks

Comment: Have you at least tried?

Comment: Do you want to know how to make a for each loop?

Comment: in C# entity framework group by give me an IGrouping object, here in Hibernate I just got a list of string with no TblVideos objects